# creating associative array from multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am using this code to get all key and values from multi dimensional array but could not send them to an array to outside function, sure I am missing some thing.

```
$users = array();
function myfunction($value,$key)
{
    $users[$key] = $value;     
}            
array_walk_recursive($data['userlevel3'],"myfunction");
```

Comment: What does `send them to an array` mean? Can you give an example input/output? It looks like you just want to copy an array: `$data = [...];
$otherArray = $data;`

Comment: In your function you can either return the new array, include `use ($users)` to allow it to access the variable or pass by reference (`&$users`).  Please don't use `global`.